# Logging in to chat does not login

Tags: bug, status-completed

On chat.stackoverflow.com:

When I am not already signed into SO:

When I go to SO chat, it asks me to log in. I let safari autofill my password and click sign in. I get redirected to the chat page that says that I have to log in.

When I am signed into SO:

I click on log in. The pages refreshes. I still am not logged in.

What is going on?

Edit: Sometimes I get the "Im working on ur problem" page

Comment: Can you describe the steps you're taking in more detail, please? Screenshots, domains you're on, etc. would be helpful.

Comment: @AdamLear I suspect this is similar to [the bug that prevented me from entering chatrooms on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281378/329351).

Comment: @dorukayhan yes that is it

Comment: @2426021684 You should be all set.

Comment: @AdamLear it works now; thanks